# What is the proper way to calculate accumulative user for everyday?

Tags: mysql, database, nosql

I have a `MySQL` table, named `transaction`, which has 5 columns, `id(int), from(int), to(int), value(float), time(datetime)`.

And I need to calculate the accumulative user `(the number of unique "from")` for some specific receiver `("to")` everyday.

For example:

```
+-----+------+-----+-------+----------------------------+
| id  | from | to  | value | time                       |
+-----+------+-----+-------+----------------------------+
| 1   |  1   | 223 |     1 | 2019-01-01 01:11:30.000000 |
| 2   |  1   | 224 |     2 | 2019-01-01 21:37:30.000000 |
| 3   |  2   |  25 |   0.1 | 2019-01-02 03:05:30.000000 |
| 4   |  2   | 223 |   0.2 | 2019-01-02 13:26:30.000000 |
| 5   |  3   |  26 |     3 | 2019-01-02 19:29:30.000000 |
| 6   |  3   | 227 |     4 | 2019-01-03 21:37:30.000000 |
| 7   |  1   | 224 |     5 | 2019-01-05 22:03:30.000000 |
| 8   |  4   | 224 |     1 | 2019-01-05 23:48:30.000000 |
| 9   |  5   | 223 |     2 | 2019-01-06 05:41:30.000000 |
| 10  |  6   |  28 |     2 | 2019-01-06 20:19:30.000000 |
+-----+------+-----+-------+----------------------------+
```

And the specific `to` is `[223, 224, 227]`

Then the expected result is:

```
2019-01-01: 1 # [1]
2019-01-02: 3 # [1, 2, 3]
2019-01-03: 3 # [1, 2, 3]
2019-01-04: 3 # [1, 2, 3]
2019-01-05: 4 # [1, 2, 3, 4]
2019-01-05: 5 # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The direct way is using `SQL`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`From`))
FROM `transaction`
FORCE INDEX (to_time_from)
WHERE `time` < '2019-01-0X'
AND `to` IN (223, 224, 227)
```

But the problem is, `transaction` table is big (1 million per day, about 2 years), and `to` list is about `1000`. The above `SQL` is very slow, even though I have created an index on `[to, time, from]` and force use it.

Besides, although daily transactions amount reaches about 1 million, the daily active user is only about 10,000. So I'm considering to store DAU list in `No-SQL`, like

```
2019-01-01: [1]
2019-01-02: [2, 3]
2019-01-03: [3]
2019-01-04: []
2019-01-05: [1, 4]
2019-01-05: [5]
```

And when given a date `d`, I just retrieve all the DAU list no later than `d` and make a union to get the accumulative user. Something like: `len(set([dau_list1]+[dau_list2]+[dau_list3]...))`

But I have no idea which `No-SQL` to use.

1. `Redis` will load everything into memory, but I only need these data when I query.
2. `MongoDB`

   1. it seems I need to create a collection for every date because I need to create a unique index on `from`. Am I right?
   2. I know I can use an array field and `$addToSet` operation. But it is `O(n)`, very slow.

So, what is the proper way to make it?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: it's mysql 5.7.20

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, use something like (no redis, no MongoDB):

```
SELECT  DATE(`time`),
        COUNT(*),
        GROUP_CONCAT(`from`)
    FROM  tbl
    WHERE  `to` IN (...)
    GROUP BY  1;    -- shorthand for "DATE(time)"

INDEX(`to`, `from`, `time`)  -- if applying to entire table
INDEX(`to`, `time`, `from`)  -- if you have `AND time ...`
```

Plus some formatting.  (Such *could* be done with a messy `CONCAT`, or left for the application code.)

Since this seems to be a 'scaling' question, too, perhaps you need a "Summary Table" that is updated daily with the previous day's entries, thereby making the queries much faster.

```
CREATE TABLE Daily (
    `day` DATE NOT NULL,
    `from` ... NOT NULL,
    `to` ... NOT NULL,
    `ct` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`to`, `day`, `from`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and the query becomes

```
SELECT  `day`,
        SUM(ct),
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `from`)
    FROM Daily
    WHERE  `to` IN (...)`
    GROUP BY `day`;
```

(It could help you provided `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERTs` to build a test case from.)